Rails 7+ Active Storage: How to open an image variant?
Latest Rails (7.1) with latest compatible ruby (3.2)
I want to analyze the variants of a certain image by opening it in my code. However, I seem to only be able access the original image.
For example, I have a large image (taken from my mobile device). I upload it to my rails server and immediately resize to fit with attachable.variant :resized, resize_to_limit: [500, 1000], preprocessed: true. I can correctly display the resized image with <%= image_tag @bill.receipt.variant(:resized) %>.
image = Bill.last.receipt.blob.open do |r| 
  ImageProcessing::Vips::Processor.load_image(r.path)
end

resized = Bill.last.receipt.variant(:resized).blob.open do |r| 
  ImageProcessing::Vips::Processor.load_image(r.path)
end

puts image # => #<Image 3072x4080 uchar, 3 bands, srgb>
puts [image.width, image.height] # => [3072, 4080]

puts resized # => #<Image 3072x4080 uchar, 3 bands, srgb>
puts [resized.width, resized.height] # => [3072, 4080] but expected is [500, 664]

I tried looking up and down the Rails guides, some google searches, but nothing came up. It seems most people are concerned with the image_tag instead of opening the resized files.
Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Add your rails version to the question

What do p image and p resized say?

I believe blob returns the original blob. Try image or processed.

Thanks to @schwern for the answer.

I believe blob returns the original blob. Try image or processed. – Schwern 17 hours ago

resized = Bill.last.receipt.variant(:resized).image.open do |r| 
  ImageProcessing::Vips::Processor.load_image(r.path)
end
# => #<Image 500x664 uchar, 3 bands, srgb>

while processed will error on the fact that open is a private method on the object.
